# liblinphone android x86_64 ffmpeg unable to load

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, x86-64, linphone-sdk

I try to use `liblinphone` with android studio using '.so' files from linphone site and I builded it by myself with ndk 9,10,11,12 versions. Always with `x86_64` platform the error appears in android monitor:

```
04-27 02:37:01.404 13883-13883/? I/LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl: Trying to load liblinphone for x86_64
04-27 02:37:01.410 13883-13883/? W/LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl: Unable to load optional library libffmpeg-linphone-x86_64
04-27 02:37:01.411 13883-13883/? I/LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl: Trying to load liblinphone for x86
04-27 02:37:01.414 13883-13883/? W/LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl: Unable to load optional library libffmpeg-linphone-x86
04-27 02:37:01.417 13883-13883/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

If I install the linphone application it works with platform `x86_64`.
Please help with it, what could i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem for `arm64` architecture, which I solved using solution mentioned below.

The best solution I’ve found so far (and be warned: it’s a nasty hack) is to simply exclude all 64-bit binaries from your APK. If there are no 64-bit dependencies found, Android will happily load the 32-bit fallback versions of all `.so`s and work just fine, assuming you’re not dependent on any 64-bit-specific functionality. To implement this in your project, follow these steps:

1. In your `gradle.properties` in the project root, add the line

   ```
   android.useDeprecatedNdk=true.
   ```
2. Add the following block to your `build.gradle` file, adding an exclude line for every 64-bit dependency:

   ```
   android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
   ...
   ndk {
       abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
   }

   packagingOptions {
       exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so"
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Once you’re done be sure to generate an APK with the new configuration and test it on an ARM64 device.

[Source of this solution](https://corbt.com/posts/2015/09/18/mixing-32-and-64bit-dependencies-in-android.html).